# django-autotranslate doesn't install, returns Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error during installation

Tags: python, django, internationalization, metadata

I'm trying to install django-auto translate but it keeps telling me:
Preparing metadata (setup.py) error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

i've also tried older versions of the package and i keep getting errors concerning metadata setup, how can i go about this?

```
Input: pip install django-autotranslate

Output:

#cmd execution after running :pip install django-autotranslate


Collecting django-autotranslate
  Using cached django_autotranslate-1.2.0-py3-none-any.whl (10 kB)
Collecting six
  Using cached six-1.16.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (11 kB)
Collecting goslate
  Using cached goslate-1.5.4.tar.gz (14 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Collecting polib
  Using cached polib-1.1.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (20 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: django in c:\users\vyktor\dev\language-translator\venv\lib\site-packages (from django-autotranslate) (4.1.2)
Requirement already satisfied: sqlparse>=0.2.2 in c:\users\vyktor\dev\language-translator\venv\lib\site-packages (from django->django-autotranslate) (0.4.3)
Requirement already satisfied: tzdata in c:\users\vyktor\dev\language-translator\venv\lib\site-packages (from django->django-autotranslate) (2022.5)
Requirement already satisfied: asgiref<4,>=3.5.2 in c:\users\vyktor\dev\language-translator\venv\lib\site-packages (from django->django-autotranslate) (3.5.2)
Collecting futures
  Using cached futures-3.0.5.tar.gz (25 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │     exit code: 1
  ╰─>   [27 lines of output]
```